# await Promise.all not waiting in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, async-await

I am trying here to make the function wait for the end of the iteration of the array. If I have understood right, this function should await for all promises to get resolved and then continue. Why is this not acting as that?

```
     async onUpdateSettings() {
            let updated = false;
            await Promise.all(Object.keys(this.settingsForm.controls).map(async (key) => {
              if (this.settingsForm.controls[key].dirty) {
                const toUpdateSetting = this.peopleSettings.find(ps => ps.settingKey.includes(key));
                toUpdateSetting.settingValue = this.settingsForm.get(key).value;
                this.peopleSettingsService.updateSetting(toUpdateSetting).subscribe(() => {
                  updated = true;
                  console.log('UPDATE');
                }, (error) => console.log(error));
              }
            }));
            console.log('DONE');
            if (updated) {
              this.toastrService.success('Settings succsessfully updated.');
            }
          }
// results always in:
// DONE
// UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE
```

Comment: Your `.map` callback must `return` a promise that `Promise.all` could await…

Comment: also the map() should not use an async function 

map(async (key) => {}) should be just map(key => {})

Comment: @deceze I thought that array.map returns a list of promises. So what should I do here?

Comment: No, the `map` just produces a list of values, and the values are whatever you `return` from the callback. You don't `return` anything from your callback.

Comment: @sp2008 check my solution below. in that map is a rxjs operator. and it should work.

Comment: @Aakash Garg thanks, I accepted it.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the explanation. I read in some articles that map returns promises, that misleaded me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code should be changed to  :-

```
async onUpdateSettings() {
        let updated = false;
        await Promise.all(Object.keys(this.settingsForm.controls).map(async (key) => {
          if (this.settingsForm.controls[key].dirty) {
            const toUpdateSetting = this.peopleSettings.find(ps => ps.settingKey.includes(key));
            toUpdateSetting.settingValue = this.settingsForm.get(key).value;
            return this.peopleSettingsService.updateSetting(toUpdateSetting).pipe(map(() => {
              updated = true;
              console.log('UPDATE');
            }), catchError(() => console.log(error))).toPromise();
          }
        }));
        console.log('DONE');
        if (updated) {
          this.toastrService.success('Settings succsessfully updated.');
        }
      }
```